# How to find papers which fall under the intersection of two different areas

Tags: publications, mathematics, independent-researcher

I am asking this question specifically for the subject of Mathematics. What are some efficient ways of searching papers on two different broad topics, say number theory and graph theory. Also, if I want to be more specific and search for papers involving phrases from number theory and graph theory? I am aware of MathScinet, Google Scholar and arXiv. However, I do not know if there are ways to serve my query in these sites.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go have a chat with your local friendly research librarian who knows the ins and outs of all the search options available where you are. If you have them, some examples of papers within your search scope and some not quite in scope may help them. They will be happy to teach you how to get good results.

Comment: These kind of papers shouldn’t be harder to find than any others. Have you tried entering relevant keywords for example in google scholar? You can use the AND operator between them.

Comment: https://semo.libguides.com/google-scholar/advanced-searching. Use advanced search options on your engine of choice

Comment: If you have MathScinet access, you can search for articles by MSC Primary or Secondary which allows you to search by mathemtical subjects. If you don't have access, a similar search can be made in zbmath which is free to use.

Comment: Scopus has far more advanced search options than Google Scholar

Comment: @theL can I put multiple MSC classes simultaneously?

Comment: @jimm, yes. Mathscinet allows this.

Comment: I agree, use MathSciNet.  It should be available at any serious research library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopus advanced search might be good. It is much better than Google Scholar in some ways.

https://www.scopus.com/search/form.uri?display=advanced

This shows an example of a search that is much more complicated than yours.

This is not a free service, so you will need access through your university or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using Scopus as well but I would also use another method.
Look up first article on topic. Click the link for articles that cite that article. Extract all the results as a list of articles.
Do the same thing for 2nd article.
Compare the two lists to identify common articles.
My current solution is to download many highly-cited papers (without reading) and index them.

Web of Science has a SAME operator, which matches “records where the terms separated by the operator appear in the same sentence”. Given that Web of Science supports four search operators (AND, OR, NOT, and SAME), it is safe to assume that this is the extent of its context-sensitive search capabilities. Then connect this to Scopus searches.

Comment: The first idea can be done directly in Scopus. Search for papers that contain the full titles of these two articles, or a distinctive phrase from each of them. This will give you a list of the papers that cite them both.